# Unresolved identifier 'HTTPMetric' when using Firebase Performance

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-performance

I'm trying to add FirebasePerformance to my app. For adding monitoring for specific network requests I used the example from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-ios

However, I get "Unresolved identifier 'HTTPMetric' ". I do have imports for Firebase & FirebasePerformance in my .swift class.

If anyone had the same issue I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, running `pod update` fixes this. I got my answer here:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1071